# getting an error "cannot find symbol" in Serializable programming

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(5, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Employee
  location: class Student
Error:(5, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Employee
  location: class Student
```

Hi, i'm making a program for serilizable in java but that's giving me that error please can you resolve and tell me what's wrong here with this?

Help would be appreciated!!

here is my source code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Student{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Employee e=new Employee(221, "My name is Rajendra Arora");

        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("D://raj1.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);

        out.writeObject(e);
        out.flush();

        System.out.println("Success....");
    }
}
```

Comment: seems you didnt `import` class `Employee`

Comment: where is Employee source defined? It seems it is not in the same default package as Student. I hope you understand java package concept

Comment: The first line of main fails to compile so it has nothing to do with Serialization, or MySQL.

Comment: sorry but i still don't get you i'm a beginer

Comment: Try eclipse organize imports: `Ctrl + Shift + O` and see if your imports change.

Comment: ohh soryy... now i got this thanks... sorry for stupid question i'm extreamly sorry for that :p

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the java files are all in the same directory

example :

```
myDirectory/Employee.java
myDirectory/Student.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported `Employee`. Import `Employee`.

Alternatively, you can keep both files in the same packge (folder), eliminating the need for imports.